# Is PHP's session_regenerate_id() collision free?

Tags: php, session, sessionid, session-hijacking

I currently working on a project in PHP (7.2). I call the `session_regenerate_id()` function on every request to prevent session hijacking attacks, (It is a small part in the whole process of detecting an hijacked session).

The question is the following: I expect to manage many sessions on my server, Should i check if the new `session_id()` value (after i called `session_regenerate_id()`) is used by another (existing) session? In other words: Is `session_regenerate_id()` collision free?

I know the function [session_create_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-create-id.php) is collision free when used in an active session (after session started), but the manual doesn't mention that about the [session_regenerate_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) function.

Any ideas / suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [`session_regenerate_id` calls `session_create_id`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5d6e923d46a89fe9cd8fb6c3a6da675aa67197b4/ext/session/mod_files.c#L673) so it's also collision free:

```
sid = php_session_create_id((void**)&data);
```